# Unable to create AKS load balance with static public IP

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer, azure-public-ip

I've followed steps mentioned over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip link.

I'm getting following error.

```
  Warning  ListPublicIPs           22s (x4 over 57s)  azure-cloud-provider  network.PublicIPAddressesClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'f76e0cc5-db5a-459a-bd4e-8c8d7b453f05' with object id 'f76e0cc5-db5a-459a-bd4e-8c8d7b453f05' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read' over scope '/subscriptions/166aaa5b-86d9-49d7-b7cc-2bf38cc91490/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
  Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  22s (x4 over 57s)  service-controller    Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: network.PublicIPAddressesClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'f76e0cc5-db5a-459a-bd4e-8c8d7b453f05' with object id 'f76e0cc5-db5a-459a-bd4e-8c8d7b453f05' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read' over scope '/subscriptions/166aaa5b-86d9-49d7-b7cc-2bf38cc91490/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
```

Answer (score 1):

you either created it in a wrong resource group or you haven't given permissions to it to AKS cluster

so basically you need to grant contributor permissions to the following application: `f76e0cc5-db5a-459a-bd4e-8c8d7b453f05` over this scope: `/subscriptions/166aaa5b-86d9-49d7-b7cc-2bf38cc91490/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup`

Comment: I have used following command to give permission. 

az role assignment create \
    --assignee ad21a8f6-d27f-4aa0-899e-ee7e0054dbcf \
    --role "Contributor" \
    --scope /subscriptions/166aaa5b-86d9-49d7-b7cc-2bf38cc91490/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup

Comment: need to wait for some time for that to start working, usually takes some time, like 15-30 minutes